# Bugzilla ./testserver.pl failing

Tags: 12.04, server, bugzilla

```
root@KittensTest:/var/www/Bugzilla/bugzilla-4.2.1# ./testserver.pl http://localhost/Bugzilla/bugzilla-4.2.1
TEST-OK Webserver is running under group id in $webservergroup.
TEST-OK Got padlock picture.
TEST-FAILED Webserver is fetching rather than executing CGI files.
Check the AddHandler statement in your httpd.conf file.
```

Well then.  httpd.conf (from [here](http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/4.2/en/html/configuration.html)[2.2.4.1.1]):

```
<Directory /var/www/Bugzilla/bugzilla-4.2.1>
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
Options +Indexes +Includes +ExecCGI
DirectoryIndex index.cgi
AllowOverride Limit FileInfo Indexes
</Directory>
```

What am I doing wrong?  I'm pretty new to this (first Bugzilla install), so I'll appreciate explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said, I'm new at this.  Turns out I was doing everything right, I just needed to restart Apache.

Comment: Since over 2 days have passed since you've posted this answer, you can accept it now (which will make clear that your problem is solved, for people searching with similar problems).